# Склеить несколько изображений в одно

Tags: изображения, android, java

Задача такова: необходимо склеить несколько изображений в одно. Как сделать это на андроиде не знаю.
Я понимаю что нужно создать холст большего размера и разместить там два изображения, но не знаю  какими средствами это сделать.
Дайте совет, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого используем классы [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) и [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).

```
// Пусть bmp1 и bmp2 -  картинки, которые нужно склеить
// Предположим, что вторую нужно нарисовать справа от первой
// Создаём изображение нужных размеров
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth() + bmp2.getWidth(), Math.max(bmp1.getHeight(), bmp2.getHeight()), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);   // Создаём canvas, на котором будем рисовать
// Рисуем bmp1
c.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, new Paint());
// Рисуем bmp2 справа от bmp1
c.drawBitmap(bmp2, bmp1.getWidth(), 0, new Paint());
```

Писал навскидку, работоспособность не проверял. Дальше копайте сами.

Comment: Хороший ответ. Хорош своей канвой ответа. Ответ синтаксически может быть и неверен, но идеологически абсолютно верен. Г-ну @boikov только останется самостоятельно копнуть дальше.

Comment: ![not sure][1]

  [1]: http://cdn.meme.li/instances/300x300/39071075.jpg